# Filter a list of type A, A containing a list of type B, with contition on an element of B in C#

Tags: c#, where-clause, generic-list

I have a list name **lstA** of Type **A**, where Type A contains a list of Type **B**:

```
List<A> lstA;

Class A()
{
    List<B> lstB;
}

Class B()
{
    string str;
}
```

I want to filter the list **lstA** where the **str** in class B has some specific value:

```
res = lstA.where(x => x.lstB.where(y => y.str == "some_value"));
```

Currently I solved it using a foreach loop on the **lstA**:

```
foreach (var l in lstA)
{
     l.lstB.RemoveAll(x => x.str != "some_value");
}
res = lstA;
```

But I don't think this is the best way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: _"I don't think this is the best way to do it"_ - why not? Does it look ugly? Does it work incorrectly? Does it perform poorly?

Comment: did `res = lstA.where(x => x.lstB.where(y => y.str == "some_value"));` and then   `lstA.lstB = res` not work? assuming you wanted to modify the original list.

Comment: hmmm it's not clear if you wana all A from lstA where lstB contains b where b str == some value or if you wana remove != value from lstB (which you do with second code)

Comment: @Selvin I want all the A from lstA, but only the Bs where the str has the value.

Comment: @CodeCaster It is not as elegant. And I will be modifying my lstA.

Comment: @Selvin No. Both solutions return the whole item of lstA including all the original B items in lstB.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to make your variables public so that they are accessible outside of the class itself, but then this should work:

```
var res = lstA.Where(x => x.lstB.Exists(y => y.str == "some_value"));
```

The reason it was not working before, was due to the fact that

```
lstB.Where(y => y.str == "some_value")
```

returns an empty string when it doesn't find your value. This is not the same as returning false, so you were not actually filtering your data. The Exists method returns a bool, so you can use that for proper filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It is returning all values of str, not only "some_value"

Comment: Your request was to filter lstA where the str in class B has some specific value. The above code finds all lsaA where the str exists in lstB. Are you trying to only return instances of "some_value"?

Comment: I want only one specific value of str. e.g. only where str == "Ready".

Comment: @dieKoderin The code provided above just filters down to only lstA where lstB has contains the value. If you wish to further filter lstB, then it would be recommended to filter the list in a for loop as you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking for, but we can simplify the below code

```
foreach (var l in lstA)
{
     l.lstB.RemoveAll(x => x.str != "some_value");
}
res = lstA;
```

with

```
lstA.ForEach(a => a.lstB.RemoveAll(x => x.str != "some_value"));
```

Comment: I want to use this as a Function that I'll use many time without manipulating my lstA